# Why are there a bunch of ╠ on the front of my packet?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock2

EDIT: The first one answers the question in the title.  It was initialized memory from my debugger.  I didn't get the program to work however.  Just going to go back to boost::asio for my sockets.  Sockets are painful.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://gafferongames.com/post/sending_and_receiving_packets/) on how to start sending and receiving packets using sockets.  I've followed the tutorial to the best of my ability, but I get a bunch of ╠'s in front of my message. Can someone explain why I'm getting these? Their ASCII code is 204 so not null nor is it 0xFF. If you need anything more, please let me know.

Bonus points: Why is my console outputting this infinitely instead of breaking out of the while loop? I'm new and don't understand. D:

Output:

```
buffer: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Hello World!
```

(times infinity)

My main class

```
#include "common_include.h"
#include "Socket.h"
#include "Address.h"

#include <string>

bool Initialize_Sockets();
void Shutdown_Sockets();

int main()
{
    Initialize_Sockets();
    constexpr int port = 30000;
    Sage::Socket socket(30000);
    if (socket.Is_Initialized() == false)
    {
        printf("Socket failed to initialize\n");
        return -1;
    }
    const char data[] = "Hello World!";
    socket.Send(Sage::Address(127, 0, 0, 1, port), data, sizeof(data));

    while (true)
    {
        Sage::Address sender;
        unsigned char buffer[256];
        int bytes_read = socket.Receive(sender, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (!bytes_read)
            break;

        printf("buffer: %s\n", buffer);
    }
    Shutdown_Sockets();
}

bool Initialize_Sockets()
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    WSADATA Wsa_Data;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Wsa_Data) == NO_ERROR;
#else
    return true;
#endif
}

void Shutdown_Sockets()
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    WSACleanup();
#endif
}
```

My socket class

```
#include "Socket.h"

Sage::Socket::Socket(unsigned short port)
{
    handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    if (handle == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Failed to create socket: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        is_created = true;
    }
#elif
    if (handle <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to create socket\n");
        is_created = false;
    }
    else
    {
        is_created = true;
    }
#endif

    sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    if (bind(handle, (sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Failed to bind socket: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        is_bound = false;
    }
    else
    {
        is_bound = true;
    }
#elif
    if (bind(handle, (const sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) < 0)
    {
        printf("failed to bind socket\n");
        is_bound = false;
    }
    else
    {
        is_bound = true;
    }
#endif

#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    DWORD non_blocking = 1;
    if (ioctlsocket(handle, FIONBIO, &non_blocking) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Failed to set socket non-blocking: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        is_non_blocking = false;
    }
    else
    {
        is_non_blocking = true;
    }
#elif
    int non_blocking = 1;
    if (fcntl(handle, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK, non_blocking) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to set socket non-blocking\n");
        is_non_blocking = false;
    }
    else
    {
        is_non_blocking = true;
    }
#endif
    is_initialized = is_created && is_bound && is_non_blocking;
    if (!is_initialized)
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize socket\n");
    }
}

int Sage::Socket::Send(Sage::Address address, const void* packet_data, int packet_size)
{
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(address.Get_Address());
    addr.sin_port = htons(address.Get_Port());

    unsigned int sendto_address = address.Get_Address();

    int sent_bytes = sendto(handle, (const char*)packet_data, packet_size, 0, (sockaddr*)&sendto_address, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    if (sent_bytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Failed to send packet: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return sent_bytes;
    }
    else if (sent_bytes != packet_size)
    {
        printf("Failed to send all bytes of packet(%d/%d)\n", sent_bytes, packet_size);
        return sent_bytes;
    }
#elif PLATFORM == PLATFORM_MAC || PLATFORM == PLATFORM_UNIX
    if (sent_bytes != packet_size)
    {
        printf("Failed to send all bytes of a packet(%d/%d)\n", sent_bytes, packet_size);
        return sent_bytes;
    }
#endif
    return sent_bytes;
}

int Sage::Socket::Receive(Sage::Address& sender, void* data, int size)
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    typedef int socklen_t;
#endif
    sockaddr_in from;
    socklen_t from_length = sizeof(from);

    int bytes_received = recvfrom(handle, (char*)data, size, 0, (sockaddr*)&from, &from_length);

    sender = Sage::Address(from);
    return bytes_received;
}

Sage::Socket::~Socket()
{
#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    closesocket(handle);
#elif PLATFORM == PLATFORM_MAC || PLATFORM == PLATFORM_UNIX
    close(handle);
#endif
}
```

Comment: You're probably missing a null terminator.

Comment: Where? I added one on the Hello World string I'm trying to send and it doesn't change the output.

Comment: I don't know where. This is (usually) what happens when you miss a zero terminator. Use a debugger to figure out.

Comment: Try this: `unsigned char buffer[256] = {0};`

Comment: What does `recvfrom` return? That could tell you something about the origin of those characters

Comment: Note that the tutorial has the condition `if ( bytes <= 0 )`, which you changed to `if (!bytes_read)`. `recvfrom` returns a negative number on failure, so you will print `buffer` in that case.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes recvfrom returns WSAEWOULDBLOCK most of the time.  Other than that, it just returns the number of received bytes as far as I can tell.

Comment: @molbdnilo That's for the example portion, the main function he wrote at the end uses !bytes_read.

Comment: @SageKing Of course, I meant how many charaters does it say it read (what *exactly* is the return value)?

Comment: Look carefully at `sockaddr_in addr;`, `unsigned int sendto_address`, and `(sockaddr*)&sendto_address`. (There appears to be a whole bunch of problems with that tutorial. Get yourself a different one.)

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes 0xFFFFFFF

Comment: @molbdnilo I wish I could, I don't like the writing in this one but it's the only one that I've found that does UDP game networking.  I did boost::asio and I think I'm just going to go back to that and try to fix up my server and client over there :(

Comment: @SageKing That looks like an error code, what does it report when it succeeds?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes I'm giving up on these sockets and going back to my boost::asio sockets and going to try to fumble my way through those.  I appreciate the help though.

Comment: @SageKing There is nothing game-specific about any of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xCCCCCCCC` is used by by Microsoft's C++ debugging runtime library to mark uninitialised stack memory.

204 is 0xCC.

Clearly you're missing a `0` in your buffer which would signal the end of the data: your output runs into the uninitialised memory.

Of course, don't rely on any of this behavior - your program behavior is undefined, but these sort of things do help to identify the problem.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values

Comment: I have a zero in my buffer, the end of my Hello World! string I'm trying to send.  Printf correctly identifies the null terminator as well.  I'm confused as to why there would be any extra characters in my buffer.  I thought my packet would just be my data in the first 12 characters and then uninitialized memory after it, which wouldn't matter since my string is null-terminated.  I appreciate the answer. :)

Comment: @SageKing does `unsigned char buffer[256] = {0};` help?

Comment: @Jabberwocky No, it just makes my console not output anything. Not even the "buffer: " string I use to tell me where the buffer starts in printf();

Comment: @SageKing inspect the content of `buffer` with the debugger right before the printf

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yeah it's all 0xCC but still prints a bunch of pipes and then my string.  I also noticed my receive function is not properly populated the sender category and the received bytes from recv_from is 0xFFFF.  Something is really wrong so I'm going to sit here and tap away at this function for a bit and come back to this thread. :(